# Resize a bitmap like MS Paint - no antialiasing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I use this method to resize a bitmap:

```
    private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)result))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It still uses antialiasing even though I specified:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

I want just a basic resizing without any smoothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
```

you should do

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
```

Comment: Not usually enough, change the PixelOffsetMode as well, use Half.

Answer (score 4):

Anti-aliasing is a sub-pixel thing, you're actually looking for [Nearest Neighbour](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx) [interpolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode.aspx) during the resize operation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [InterpolationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode.aspx) property.

I think that's what you want.  [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScalingResizingResamplingAnImageInASPNET.aspx) has a good blog article on it.